# style navbar list items after changing inner HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a navbar in the header bar which gets initialized and styled correctly. The problem I'm having is when I change the innerHtml and call elem.navbar() the list items don't get styled.

Here's the code that appends to the navbar html

```
var navbar = this.$(':jqmData(role="navbar")');
navbar.empty().append(this.templateNav(building.toJSON()));
navbar.navbar();
```

And Here's the template I'm using

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#buildings/1/floors/1">1</a></li>
</ul>
```

My question is how do I make jqm recalculate the grid layout and re-style the list items after I append new html?

Before

[image: Navbar before appending to innerHTML]

After

[image: Navbar after appending to innerHTML]

Comment: It would really help if you could post a jsfiddle.
Maybe using refresh would work, take a look here: http://andymatthews.net/read/2011/12/14/Refreshing-jQuery-Mobile-listviews,-buttons,-select-dropdowns,-and-input-fields

Comment: @Hessius Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJJbP/) to show the problem I was having  . Turns out replaceWith doesn't return the new jquery object. The way around it is querying again after using replaceWith, then calling navbar() on the new object. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKhBS/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the navbar element from DOM. Afterwards recreate it and **trigger** the **create** event to handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within the new HTML markup.

The following script has been successfully tested:

```
var navbarparent = $('#navbar').parent();
$('#navbar').remove();
navbarparent.html("<div data-role=\"navbar\"><ul><li><a class=\"nav-li\" href=\"a.html\">Two</a></li><li><a class=\"nav-li\" href=\"a.html\">Three</a></li></ul></div>").trigger('create');
```

Below you can find a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Navbar Test</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('click', '.nav-li', function(e){
                var navbarparent = $('#navbar').parent();
                $('#navbar').remove();
                navbarparent.html("<div data-role=\"navbar\"><ul><li><a class=\"nav-li\" href=\"a.html\">Two</a></li><li><a class=\"nav-li\" href=\"a.html\">Three</a></li></ul></div>").trigger('create');
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Dynamic Navbar</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="navbar" data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="nav-li" href="test.html">One</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKhBS/1/) to a slightly altered version of your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about `templateNav` or `building`, this seemed to have worked for me:

*Mockup of `building` JSON object and `templateNav`:*

```
buildingJson = [
  {"href":"foo.html",
   "title":"One"},
  {"href":"bar.html",
   "title":"Two"}          
]

function templateNav( json ){
  str = "";
  for( i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    str += '<li><a href="'+json[i].href+'">'+json[i].title+'</a></li>';
  }
  return str;
}
```

*Updating `navbar`*

```
var navbar = this.$(':jqmData(role="navbar") ul');
navbar.empty().append(templateNav(buildingJson));
```

*HTML*

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="a.html">One</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

I'm not sure what your code looks like; if your `ul` is wrapped by a `div` with `data-role=navbar`, then after you `empty` it you'll need to make sure `templateNav` wraps the results in a `ul`, or update the selector for `navbar` to include the `ul`. Try logging `templateNav` before you append it to see what's actually being appended.

Regardless, `navbar.navbar()` doesn't appear to be necessary, even after dynamically changing innerHTML.